# Paralelizar com apenas um núcleo?

Tags: python, paralelismo, cpu

Estou querendo paralelizar uma aplicação, no caso um cálculo de 'cosine similarity', porém a máquina no qual estou trabalhando possui apenas um core.
Paralelizar essa cálculo com apenas um core terá algum ganho significativo?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Como você mesmo desconfia, não, não terá nenhum aumento de performance nesse caso.

Se a máquina tiver hiperthreading - ou seja: dois cores "visíveis" mas um só núcleo físico nesse caso, dependeria do modelo da CPU - ela teria que ter duas FPUs internas, e teria que ser feito um bom trabalho na hora de distribuir as tarefas para o overhead de paralelizar não ficar acima do ganho mínimo que você poderia ter aí.

Mas aí vamos para outras considerações: você quer "paralelizar", ou quer "acelerar" seu cálculo? Paralelizar para aprender a fazer isso é uma coisa. Só querer mais desempenho é outra.

Se você está usando Python, e expressando as operações em Python puro (e não usando alguma coisa como a NumPy, que tem código para processamento numérico), seu programa pode estar de 1000 a 10000 vezes mais lento que o mesmo programa rodando em código nativo.

Se você em vez de rodar seu programa no Python normal, usar o [Pypy](https://pypy.org/) - o "Python feito em Python", que tem um mecanismo de JIT, terá um ganho de cerca de 10 vezes no desempenho de código puramente numérico.

Se você usar o [Cython](http://cython.org/) - um super-conjunto de Python que compila o programa pra C, e permite que você defina os tipos dos seus dados numéricos (assim, seus números podem ser um int64 nativo, em vez de um objeto do tipo int do Python),  pode chegar bem perto da performance nativa (ou seja, mais de 1000 vezes mais rápido).

Dito tudo isso, é possível "paralelizar" o código, ao aproveitar os recursos que as CPUs modernas tem para cálculos numéricos mesmo num único núcleo - isso é, se você puder escrever o seu código de forma que use as instruções AVX da Intel, por exemplo. (De quebra qualquer módulo que deixe você tirar proveito desse paralelismo numérico da CPU também vai estar usando números nativos, oferendo muitos dos ganhos descritos acima). Um dos projetos que parece estar ativo que faz isso é o [PyOpenCL](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pyopencl) - que pode usar o OpenCL para fazer uso das características avançadas da sua CPU ou mesmo usar sua placa de vídeo.